# How to create a transition of a div from behind an icon?

Tags: html, css

I have these two elements: a div with border-radius on one side and a font-awesome close icon (far fa-times-circle)

[image: The elements]

```
<div class="Close">
    <a class="CloseButton far fa-times-circle"></a>
    <div class="CloseTag">Close</div>
</div>
```

Now I need that only the close icon be visible,like this:

[image: Close Icon]

But upon hover over the close icon, the div should come in from behind the icon towards the left and the right side of div should stop at the centre of the icon. I know `transition` is to be used but I couldn't get it to work.  The result expected looks like this:

[image: Result]

Also, the icon has a transparent background which would make the part of the div behind the icon visible. How do I make the background white but only inside the circle. Upon using `background-color: white` I get a rectangle with white background. How do I make the border of the icon a circle?

This is what I could do so far. I don't know how to manage the position of the div and how to control the text in the div.

```css
.Close
{
 height: 30px;
 width: 80px;
}

.CloseButton
{
 float: right;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: lightgrey;
 transition: 1.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.CloseButton:hover
{
 color: black;
}

.CloseTag
{
 float: right;
 width: 0;
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
 transition: 1.5s;
}

.CloseButton:hover+.CloseTag
{
 width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="Close">
  <a class="CloseButton far fa-times-circle"></a>
  <div class="CloseTag">Close</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this something that can be useful for you? here is working sample, maybe you could only change some of elements like close image etc: https://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/ZorYLO

Comment: You can try making the .CloseButton background: white; and the .CloseTag a position: relative; with a margin that you can change on hover. Also you should set an overflow: hidden; to the .Close div. I recommend you to provide the CSS you have so far!

Comment: @JuanElfers I added the CSS. Check if you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? Use position absolute to set position of icon and tag

```css
.Close
{
 height: 30px;
 width: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.CloseButton
{
 position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 3px;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: lightgrey;
 transition: 1.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.CloseButton:hover
{
 color: black;
}

.CloseTag
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-indent: 2px;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 text-align: left;
 border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
 transition: 1.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 8px;
}

.CloseButton:hover+.CloseTag
{
 width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="Close">
  <a class="CloseButton far fa-times-circle"></a>
  <div class="CloseTag">Close</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfectly what I was wishing for. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="Close">
 <div class="CloseTag">Close</div>
 <div class="CloseButton">x</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family:arial;
 }
.Close{
  width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  margin-top:60px;


 }
 .CloseButton{
  width:38px;
  height:38px;
  border-radius:50%;
  float:left;
  border:2px solid black;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:5px;

 }
.CloseTag{
   display:inline-block;
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
  float:left;
  padding:10px 15px;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  left:20px;
  z-index:-999;
  border-top-left-radius:25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:25px;


  }
```

JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName("CloseButton")[0].onmouseover=function()
 {
  var a=document.getElementsByClassName("CloseTag")[0];
   a.style.left="0px";
   a.style.transition="0.5s";

   }
  document.getElementsByClassName("CloseButton")[0].onmouseout=function()
  {
   var a=document.getElementsByClassName("CloseTag")[0];
   a.style.left="20px";
   a.style.transition="0.5s";
   }
```

Comment: I need the div to come out upon hovering over the icon. Making the  div go right is completely opposite of what I want;

Comment: Thanks for the help but @ChrisLi's answer solved the problem.